# Attach PKCS7 Signature data externally

Tags: itext, bouncycastle

I have PKCS7 CMS block , which contains content info and signature data. I used Bouncy Castle to extract information from PKCS7 bytes and do not have any private key.

Now I want to attach these signatures in PDF externally, so that It would be appear like a signed block in PDF at particular position. I read iText PDF library, but not able to get much help on attaching part. Can someone guide me on this.

Comment: If you don't have any private key, you can not sign a document. If it were possible to make something appear "like a signed block in PDF", then you would be able to forge a signature. Your question is either unclear, or it's a request to do something that is illegal (and fortunately impossible).

Comment: @Bruno May be, My question is unclear. I read your book iText in action. My query is related to section of book 12.4.5 Creating the digest and signing externally. I sent a hash of the document to an external service, It send me PKCS7 CMS bytes, which contains content info and signature data and also X509 certificate. In this case , I just need to attach received signature block to PDF. I tried using your examples given, but did not get success.

Comment: That is called deferred signing. That is totally different. The examples in "iText in Action" are outdated. Even the example in [Digital Signatures for PDF](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-digital-signatures-for-pdf.html) is outdated. You need the [DeferredSigning](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/security/digital-signatures-white-paper/digital-signatures-chapter-4#881-c4_09_deferredsigning.java) example.

Comment: It means I need to use emptySignature(String src, String dest, String fieldname, Certificate[] chain) method. Certificate chain , I can get from PKCS7 bytes using Bouncy Castle.

Comment: It means that you use `signExternalContainer()` using an `ExternalBlankSignatureContainer` on your machine to create the PDF with an empty signature. The result is a PDF with an invalid signature (because the signature consists of `0000...00`). You then send the bytes that need to be signed to the machine where the private key resides. As soon as you receive the signed bytes, you use `signedDeferred()` to replace the `00000...00` by the actual signature.

Comment: is this can be done using this.   PdfDictionary dic2 = new PdfDictionary();
          dic2.put(PdfName.CONTENTS, new PdfString(Pkcs7Bytes).setHexWriting(true));

Comment: If *is this can be done using this.* is a question, then the answer is: *it depends.* on the value of `Pkcs7Bytes`. It's very easy to make a mistake, hence we advise to use the `signDeferred()` method. It seems that you are reading the duplicate *question* (the one that causes an error) instead of reading the answer to that question.